# Camera not showing objects in rendered view

Tags: objects

I've been following Blender Guru's donut tutorial series as I'm completely new to Blender and 3d software in general, and everything has been working out great so far. However, I've found a peculiar issue. Suddenly, whenever I go into my camera view while in rendered mode, nothing shows up, mainly just grey. if I switch to solid view, bam, there's my donut and coffee. If needed, I'm currently on part 2 of level 4 in the tutorial series. Idk if this was a setting I messed up at some point or what, but help is appreciated!

Comment: in the Outliner, click on the funnel icon to activate the Disable In Renders option (camera icon), and make sure it is activated for your objects?

Comment: Moonboots: Those rendering toggles in the Outliner only affects actual rendering output results, not the visibility of objects when using the "Rendered" viewport display option, which normally continues to work, even if the rendering toggles are off in the Outliner. I believe the OP is referring only to the Rendered viewport mode.